# Seeking a way to have a "Hover button" to expand a section

Tags: delphi, components

i have a flow panel that i'm adding extra items to it at runtime based on whether they have chosen to show all the items.  that's all works fine; the expansion is controlled by a toolbar button.

the trouble is we'd like the user to be able to move his mouse over the "+" sign to expand the section.

[image]

initially i looked at TSpeedButton (OnMouseEnter) but even when it's "Flat", the focus rectangle still shows and so the glyph isn't centered.  the main problem with this solution is it's appearance.

then i looked at making a descendant of TImage.  that's a bit "unconventional" but it'd work.  in OnMouseEnter or OnClick, it'd toggle an internal boolean "Expanded" flag and then load the appropriate picture from a resource.  i have a dislike for unconventional solutions like that.

i need to add it to a few different screens so it's probably prudent for me to have/build a component for this.  i have JVCL but i don't see anything suitable offhand.

thank you for your comments/help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always liked the approach used by the [ModelMaker Code Explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html).

For example, when you're adding a new method, some rarely-used stuff is displayed collapsed ('Options and Directives' in the image below).

[image]
<sub>(source: [17slon.com](http://17slon.com/krama/expand-mmx-1.png))</sub>

When you hover over the text, you notice that it's actually a flat button. (Except that it's not - I believe Gerrit does some custom painting magic here).

[image]
<sub>(source: [17slon.com](http://17slon.com/krama/expand-mmx-2.png))</sub>

When you click this button, a panel appears. Button is still there, but with a new image. You can click it to close the panel.

[image]
<sub>(source: [17slon.com](http://17slon.com/krama/expand-mmx-3.png))</sub>

The state of this toggle button is preserved between sessions. IOW, even if you restart the Delphi, next tima you invoke 'Add Method', the 'Options and Directives' panel will appear exactly as you left it the last time.

Comment: thank you gabr; i think i'll do it that way.  thank you for your answers on stackoverflow; i see your contributions often!

Answer (score 1):

> i have a dislike for unconventional solutions like that.

Over the past few years, I have grown a bit suspicious of unconventional *UI* solutions — which is what you seem to be creating here. Why not just use a button that the user actually has to *click*? That seems to be much more common in the software I use, be it MS Office or programming utilities. Also, I'd make the button somewhat larger: in the screenshot, it really seems like a tiny little thing you have to target with your mouse cursor. Oh well, and if I'm bugging you with advise you haven't asked for anyway, why not give it ">>" as a caption instead of "+"? And if you'd give it a textual caption with a mnemonic as well, it'd actually be keyboard accessible. All this should make your UI better and more intuitive. I guess.

I do apologize for not answering your question, but I hope you'll spend 2 minutes thinking whether your users would actually prefer this solution :-)

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your reply.  i share your concern & consider the design i mentioned to be a "bad smell".  it's those guys in marketing!  ;-)

Comment: @Onnodb- Sometimes is about available screen space. You have to consider also the users with resolutions of 1024x768 pix. For large applications with lots of controls is difficult to put all buttons belonging to one module/functionality/section on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think that using a TImage in this situation is pretty conventional. I have seen many people suggest using the TImage, when either the TButton, or any of its associates did not have the right amount of control for whatever the developer was trying to do.

Have you tried a TBitBtn? I think when you get rid of the text it centers whatever image you have associated with it. I just checked in Delphi 6, all I have installed on this machine, and it had the MouseMove event.

Comment: than you for your comment.  i haven't tried TBitBtn.  i think i must talk more with the project manager & marketing.